# fd.seek() IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: python, python-2.6

My Python Interpreter (v2.6.5) raises the above error in the following codepart:

```
fd = open("some_filename", "r")
fd.seek(-2, os.SEEK_END) #same happens if you exchange the second arg. w/ 2
data=fd.read(2);
```

last call is fd.seek()

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "bot.py", line 250, in <module>
        fd.seek(iterator, os.SEEK_END);
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

The strange thing with this is that the exception occurs just when executing my entire code, not if only the specific part with the file opening.
At the runtime of this part of code, the opened file definitely exists, disk is not full, the variable "iterator" contains a correct value like in the first codeblock.
What could be my mistake?

Thanks in advance

Comment: is it possible that your file is empty? So that it can't seek all the way back to -2?

Comment: just double checked it, the file is existing at both times, before the open end before the seek.

Comment: the file exists AND has something in it? A file can exist but still be empty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From `lseek(2)`:

> EINVAL
>
> whence is not one of SEEK_SET,
>   SEEK_CUR, SEEK_END; or the resulting
>   file offset would be negative, or
>   beyond the end of a seekable device.

So double-check the value of `iterator`.

Comment: it is definitely -2 in the first cycle of the loop, which is also the point at which it's crashing...

Comment: "or the resulting file offset would be negative". What is the file size?

Comment: you got it... it was ZERO
although I wonder why, do I have to .close() a file first before next read?

Comment: closing and reopening the file in every loop cycle is the solution :) thanks